# How to fix an empty output (data) when the script first run (JS)

Tags: javascript

I wrote a JS script to run notifications every 10 seconds. 
This script works fine, but there is a problem. 
The **FIRST** notification (data) output is blank.

```js
var array = [["Damu Rizki Tari",793,31],["Eman Latupono",784,28],["Salsabila Kamil",954,23],["Laila Astuti",673,38],["Wakiman Martana",117,45],["Irma Sakura Agu",515,52],["Liman Pangestu",137,45],["Ismail Zulkarna",765,58],["Dalima Yuliarti",161,27],["Elvina Dewi Pad",896,42],["Dono Irwan Sima",725,26],["Ade Putra",863,7],["Tirtayasa Agus ",753,26],["Unggul Prasetyo",844,9],["Citra Zulaikha ",267,4],["Ani Rahmawati",659,3],["Parman Prasasta",582,26],["Dalimin Baktiad",512,32],["Jaka Dacin Sire",810,10],["Chelsea Padmasa",177,54],["Jasmani Rajasa",923,40],["Elvina Rahayu",784,3],["Samsul Raden Me",423,32],["Nova Wulandari ",41,33],["Uchita Restu Na",984,54],["Hamzah Wijaya",269,42],["Dadap Bagus Hut",360,7],["Febi Wijayanti",814,6],["Embuh Dasa Walu",549,39],["Aris Garda Siho",262,47]];

setInterval(function() {
  var buyer = array[Math.random() * array.length | 0];

  document.getElementById("random").innerHTML = buyer[0] + ", membeli<br><b>$" + buyer[1] + "</b> Saldo PayPal<small>" + buyer[2] + " menit lalu</small>";
  $(".custom-social-proof").stop().slideToggle('fast');
}, 8000);

$(".custom-close").click(function() {
  $(".custom-social-proof").stop().slideToggle('fast');
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600');
.custom-social-proof {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  z-index: 9999999999999 !important;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.custom-social-proof .custom-notification {
  width: 320px;
  border: 0;
  text-align: left;
  z-index: 99999;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-weight: 400;
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px 2px rgba(11, 10, 10, 0.2);
  background-color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.custom-social-proof .custom-notification .custom-notification-container {
  display: flex !important;
  align-items: center;
  height: 80px;
}

.custom-social-proof .custom-notification .custom-notification-container .custom-notification-image-wrapper img {
  max-height: 75px;
  width: 90px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 6px 0 0 6px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.custom-social-proof .custom-notification .custom-notification-container .custom-notification-content-wrapper {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  color: gray;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  border-radius: 0 6px 6px 0;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex !important;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.custom-social-proof .custom-notification .custom-notification-container .custom-notification-content-wrapper .custom-notification-content {
  font-family: inherit !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 16px;
}

.custom-social-proof .custom-notification .custom-notification-container .custom-notification-content-wrapper .custom-notification-content small {
  margin-top: 3px !important;
  display: block !important;
  font-size: 12px !important;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.custom-social-proof .custom-notification .custom-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 8px;
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  opacity: 0;
}

.custom-social-proof .custom-notification .custom-close::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: gray;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 5px;
}

.custom-social-proof .custom-notification .custom-close::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 2px;
  background-color: gray;
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  top: 0;
}

.custom-social-proof .custom-notification:hover .custom-close {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="custom-social-proof">
  <div class="custom-notification">
    <div class="custom-notification-container">
      <div class="custom-notification-image-wrapper">
        <img src="https://tidings.today/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/tidings-today-logo-fav.png">
      </div>
      <div class="custom-notification-content-wrapper">
        <p id="random" class="custom-notification-content"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-close"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

i need the first notification to be printed not blank

### Thanks for your time

Comment: Just hide the notification element initially? `.custom-social-proof { display: none; }`

Comment: add display:none to class- custom-social-proof  - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/ZZNjjd

Comment: Hello felix-kling, naga-sai-a Thank you very much for your help, I appreciate that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested above, set `.custom-social-proof` to `display:none` to begin with.

The reason as to why its blank when it firsts starts is because there is no text set when it first shows until the JS kicks in.

```js
var array = [["Damu Rizki Tari",793,31],["Eman Latupono",784,28],["Salsabila Kamil",954,23],["Laila Astuti",673,38],["Wakiman Martana",117,45],["Irma Sakura Agu",515,52],["Liman Pangestu",137,45],["Ismail Zulkarna",765,58],["Dalima Yuliarti",161,27],["Elvina Dewi Pad",896,42],["Dono Irwan Sima",725,26],["Ade Putra",863,7],["Tirtayasa Agus ",753,26],["Unggul Prasetyo",844,9],["Citra Zulaikha ",267,4],["Ani Rahmawati",659,3],["Parman Prasasta",582,26],["Dalimin Baktiad",512,32],["Jaka Dacin Sire",810,10],["Chelsea Padmasa",177,54],["Jasmani Rajasa",923,40],["Elvina Rahayu",784,3],["Samsul Raden Me",423,32],["Nova Wulandari ",41,33],["Uchita Restu Na",984,54],["Hamzah Wijaya",269,42],["Dadap Bagus Hut",360,7],["Febi Wijayanti",814,6],["Embuh Dasa Walu",549,39],["Aris Garda Siho",262,47]];

setInterval(function() {
  var buyer = array[Math.random() * array.length | 0];

  document.getElementById("random").innerHTML = buyer[0] + ", membeli<br><b>$" + buyer[1] + "</b> Saldo PayPal<small>" + buyer[2] + " menit lalu</small>";
  $(".custom-social-proof").slideToggle('fast');
}, 1000);

$(".custom-close").click(function() {
  $(".custom-social-proof").stop().slideToggle('fast');
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600');
.custom-social-proof {
  position: fixed;
  display:none;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  z-index: 9999999999999 !important;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.custom-social-proof .custom-notification {
  width: 320px;
  border: 0;
  text-align: left;
  z-index: 99999;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-weight: 400;
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px 2px rgba(11, 10, 10, 0.2);
  background-color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.custom-social-proof .custom-notification .custom-notification-container {
  display: flex !important;
  align-items: center;
  height: 80px;
}

.custom-social-proof .custom-notification .custom-notification-container .custom-notification-image-wrapper img {
  max-height: 75px;
  width: 90px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 6px 0 0 6px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.custom-social-proof .custom-notification .custom-notification-container .custom-notification-content-wrapper {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  color: gray;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  border-radius: 0 6px 6px 0;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex !important;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.custom-social-proof .custom-notification .custom-notification-container .custom-notification-content-wrapper .custom-notification-content {
  font-family: inherit !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 16px;
}

.custom-social-proof .custom-notification .custom-notification-container .custom-notification-content-wrapper .custom-notification-content small {
  margin-top: 3px !important;
  display: block !important;
  font-size: 12px !important;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.custom-social-proof .custom-notification .custom-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 8px;
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  opacity: 0;
}

.custom-social-proof .custom-notification .custom-close::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: gray;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 5px;
}

.custom-social-proof .custom-notification .custom-close::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 2px;
  background-color: gray;
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  top: 0;
}

.custom-social-proof .custom-notification:hover .custom-close {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="custom-social-proof">
  <div class="custom-notification">
    <div class="custom-notification-container">
      <div class="custom-notification-image-wrapper">
        <img src="https://tidings.today/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/tidings-today-logo-fav.png">
      </div>
      <div class="custom-notification-content-wrapper">
        <p id="random" class="custom-notification-content"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-close"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move most of the logic from within the `setInterval` into its own function which you can call separately when the page loads. This will ensure that the initial notification isn't blank.

```
var array = [["Damu Rizki Tari",793,31],["Eman Latupono",784,28],["Salsabila Kamil",954,23],["Laila Astuti",673,38],["Wakiman Martana",117,45],["Irma Sakura Agu",515,52],["Liman Pangestu",137,45],["Ismail Zulkarna",765,58],["Dalima Yuliarti",161,27],["Elvina Dewi Pad",896,42],["Dono Irwan Sima",725,26],["Ade Putra",863,7],["Tirtayasa Agus ",753,26],["Unggul Prasetyo",844,9],["Citra Zulaikha ",267,4],["Ani Rahmawati",659,3],["Parman Prasasta",582,26],["Dalimin Baktiad",512,32],["Jaka Dacin Sire",810,10],["Chelsea Padmasa",177,54],["Jasmani Rajasa",923,40],["Elvina Rahayu",784,3],["Samsul Raden Me",423,32],["Nova Wulandari ",41,33],["Uchita Restu Na",984,54],["Hamzah Wijaya",269,42],["Dadap Bagus Hut",360,7],["Febi Wijayanti",814,6],["Embuh Dasa Walu",549,39],["Aris Garda Siho",262,47]];

function displayBuyer(){
  var buyer = array[Math.random() * array.length | 0];
  document.getElementById("random").innerHTML = buyer[0] + ", membeli<br><b>$" + buyer[1] + "</b> Saldo PayPal<small>"+buyer[2]+" menit lalu</small>";
}

setInterval(function(){
  $(".custom-social-proof").stop().slideToggle('fast');
  displayBuyer();
}, 8000);

$(".custom-close").click(function() {
  $(".custom-social-proof").stop().slideToggle('fast');
});

displayBuyer();
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I didn't realize the `| 0` was actually using a binary OR to floor your random number, which apparently works because all binary operations work on signed 32bit ints. It does work, but it's a bad practice because it makes your code hard to understand. In general, I would avoid binary operations unless you're doing extremely low level stuff and know exactly what you're doing.

You've got some errors in the line `var buyer = array[Math.random() * array.length | 0];`. First of all, Math.random() returns a float between 0 and 1, so something like `0.547676`, but you can't use a float as an array index. You need to use an integer instead, like `0`, `1`, or `2`. There's also no reason for your `| 0` check, which does nothing. To fix it, you need to floor it so that it's an int. Here's what it should look like:

```
let randomI = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);
const buyer = array[randomI];
```

Comment: **[`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) never returns 1**

Comment: Whoops, you are correct sir. I've edited to fix it.

Comment: Interesting, I assumed he was trying to do `|| 0`. I've never seen someone do a binary OR to floor something, but it apparently does work. I would still consider it a bad practice because it makes the code less readable.